# Replace invocation values for std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have stored `std::function`, which are results of `std::bind`, in a list:

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::function<void(HDC)>> myPair;

std::list<myPair> *paintJobs;
paintJobs = new std::list<myPair>();
```

I then I add something like this:

```
int id = 1;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int width = 100;
int height = 100;
int r = 255;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;
std::function<void(HDC)> func = std::bind(&Window::drawRect, this, std::placeholders::_1, x, y, width, height, r, g, b);
paintJobs->push_back(std::make_pair(id, func));
```

In my paint method I go through the list and call all the functions, I have added. This part works well.

But now, I want to exchange for example the color (the r, g and b):

```
void changeColor(int id, int r, int g, int b) {
   for(auto elem = paintJobs->begin(); elem != paintJobs->end(); ++elem) {
        if(elem->first == id){

            //change the 6th, 7th and 8th parameter of elem->second
        }
    }
}
```

My other idea was to insert a new entry and copying the old values, but there is the other problem: getting the bound values.

So how can I replace the bound values of the parameters or getting the values of the other ones?

Comment: [OT]: `std::list<myPair> *paintJobs;`... uneeded pointer, `std::list<myPair> paintJobs;` is probably what you want.

Comment: It is a little bit more complicated in a class embedded, thus the pointer

Comment: If you want to change the "members" then you should create a functor and provide access to them.  Then you can store that functor instead of a `std::function`.

Comment: You probably want an interface instead of `std::function`, with `void changeColor(int r, int g, int b)`, `void Draw(HDC)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a `std::function<void(HDC, int r, int g, int b)>` (or equivalent) instead of a `std::function<void(HDC)>`.  Also store a `struct {int r,g,b;}`.

```
struct rgb { int r,g,b; };
struct rgb_func {
  rgb color;
  std::function<void(HDC, rgb)> f;
  void operator()(HDC hdc)const{
    return f(hdc, color);
  }
};

std::function<void(HDC, rgb)> func =
  [this, x, y, width, height](HDC hdc, rgb color)->void
  {
    this->drawRect( hdc, x, y, width, height, color.r, color.g, color.b );
  };
paintJobs->push_back(std::make_pair(id, rgb_func{ {r,g,b}, func }));
```

then to change it:

```
void changeColor(int id, int r, int g, int b) {
  for(auto elem = paintJobs->begin(); elem != paintJobs->end(); ++elem) {
    if(elem->first == id){
      elem->second.color = {r,g,b};
    }
  }
}
```

note that the type of `second` is no longer a `std::function<void(HDC)>`, but it is convertible-to a `std::function<void(HDC)>` but not from it.  Such conversion could result in modest overhead; use of `auto&` would avoid it in that case.

Code not tested; design is sound.  There are probably tpyos.  I would make `rgb` be a bit nicer (like, guarantee zeroing or whatever).

I used lambda instead of `std::bind`, because `std::bind` is confusing and was pretty much obsolete when it was added to `std`.

As an aside

```
void changeColor(int id, int r, int g, int b) {
  for(auto& elem:*paintJobs) {
    if(elem.first == id){
      elem.second.color = {r,g,b};
    }
  }
}
```

is a lot less messy.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a solution like the following:

1. Store your bound parameters elsewhere.
2. Pass to your function `std::bind(f, ..., std::ref(param)...)`

The idea is to be able to modify the parameters:

```
std::function<void(HDC)> func = std::bind(&Window::drawRect, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(x)...
```

Now you can modify the parameters from outside, when the function is called again it will use the new values.

Another solution would be to change the signature of your `std::function` to take the parameters for every call.